# How to remove GRUB boot launcher from Windows 10 without a recovery disk

Tags: windows-10

I installed ubuntu a while ago and then removed it soon after. Now Windows 10 is back to normal apart from GRUB boot launcher is activated and I have to type "exit" to exit it and go into Windows 10.

I do not have a windows recovery disk or USB either so I am unsure how to remove it.

Comment: You can create a recovery and installation DVD/USB of Windows free of charge. Microsoft will just nag you if you install from it without a valid license key but you don't seem to want to do that anyway. In any case that's a Windows question. Here on AskUbuntu we're very good at installing and fixing Ubuntu but when it comes to removing Ubuntu or fixing Windows' boot process you'd be better off on out sister site [SU].

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two ways using the command prompt or by using EasyBCD(not sure if it is possible with windows 10).
**The Command prompt method**

1. Open command prompt(Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and choose command prompt)
2. Enter `bootsect /nt60 <drive name>: /mbr`